# open angular mat-dialog on canvas click in full-screen mode

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-canvas, mat-dialog

I have one canvas and one angular matiral dialog.

The funcationality is if i am clicked on canvas in any place the angular matiral dialog is open
and this funcationality is working fine.

but my question is if I add canvas on full screen using bellow code the dialog is not open
it's open behind the full screen.

```
this.document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].requestFullscreen()
```

so my question is how i can open dialog on canvas click in full-screen mode

basically how i can overlay the angular mat-dialog with the full-screen mode in canvas